# How to serve Angular App with Spring?

Tags: angularjs, spring

I am currently learning Spring.
So I did one or two of the getting started guides (which are awesome btw) and Set Up a little REST Server. I tested it by building a little AngularApp consuming the REST endpoint, which worked fine.

Now the next step is to let the server serve the Angular App. But how do I accomplish that in the most simple way? It should only be loosely coupled and communicate via REST.

Is that possible with pure Java (without XML, I haven't really dug into that yet)?

Best regards!

Comment: What you want to do is to *serve static resources* - when you search for this term you'll get tens of results and older questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @kryger I did that. Everything I found included tons of XML configs. All I really want to do though, is serving the app itself. I want to get a REST request, and return the whole thing. That's it. The communication is supposed to work with different REST Apis. Is XML not avoidable is that scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible with pure Java. Start with [spring-boot](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/). The quick start example is good enough. Use the standard maven folder structure. The static resources including angular can go into the folder `src/main/resources/static`. The resources/static folder gets mapped to the root of the context. So `src/main/resources/static/index.html` gets mapped to `<webcontext>/index.html`. And no need for the HelloController in the example.

This is a simple setup. For a more complete one, you might need a dependency and build system for the client code as well - various combination of bower, grunt, gulp..

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you said about pure Java and XML means. I think it refers to the configuration for Spring.

Spring supports pure Java configuration on its own, but in essential that's no difference between Java and XML configuration. Using spring-boot does not necessarily mean it needn't configuration at all.

When you'd like serve AngularJS using Spring MVC for REST services, another thing I must mention is the CORS problem. You can write a filter to allow CORS so that AngularJS won't complain about that.